# Milliseconds to UNIX timestamp

Tags: java, android

Anyone have any idea how I would go about converting a timestamp in milliseconds from `1970` (from Android's `System.currentTimeMillis();`) to a UNIX timestamp? It need only be accurate to the day.

I figure I could divide by `1000` to get seconds, and then divide by `86400` (number of seconds in a day) to get the # of days. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Many thanks.

Comment: Aren't "UNIX timestamps" also measured in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970?

Comment: @matt: No, they're seconds from 1/1/1970.

Comment: Don't try to do the date math yourself to get seconds into a date.  Let java do that part for you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Divide it by 1000

Answer (score 8):

Dividing by 1000 is enough to get a Unix timestamp. You don't need any numbers of days or anything like that.

Answer (score 6):

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```